# Catching "socket hang up" error in request module

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I'm using the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) module to send requests (GET & POST) to a 3rd-party API.

I'm using the **timeout** option to limit the waiting time for the response (can't wait too long for it).

The problem is that sometimes the following exception is thrown:

> Error: socket hang up at createHangUpError (http.js:1476:15) at
>   Socket.socketCloseListener (http.js:1526:23) at Socket.emit
>   (events.js:117:20) at TCP.close (net.js:465:12)

I'm guessing that's because requests are aborted (due to timeout) but the socket is still open and hangs up after 2 minutes.

The question is - what can I do to close the socket when a request is aborted or how to catch this exception and handle it gracefully.

Here is the relevant code I use:

```
var request = require('request'),
    requestOptions = {
        url: 'http://example.com/api',
        timeout: 1000
    };

request(requestOptions, function onResponse(error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
        //Trying to close the socket (to prevent socket hang up errors)
        //**Doesn't help**
        this.req.socket.destroy();
        this.req.destroy();
        return;
    }

    //Handle the response
});
```

Comment: I ran into something very similar with Node's `http.get`.  Not sure if this would help in your case, but a try/catch did not catch it.  However, when I did an `http.get(url, options, res => {}).on('error', e => { console.log(e); }`, I was able to successfully trap the socket hang up error.